# Manually downloading JAR from Google Maven

Tags: android, maven

I'm trying to manually download some JAR files from Google Maven.
Following [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#google-maven) doesn't seem to work.
For example:

- I'm able to download POM from URL: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/1.1.0/rules-1.1.0.pom
- But I get 404 when trying to download JAR from URL: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/1.1.0/rules-1.1.0.jar

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the library is not a **jar** but an **aar** (Android Archive). Try

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/test/rules/1.1.0/rules-1.1.0.aar

And it will work.

Edit: You can determine this from the `<packaging>` tag in the pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>androidx.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>rules</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.